# How do I create properly sectioned lists from a table in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a particular column (& its data) from a table

So what I did was

```
list <- list(sample_table$column)
```

but it returned me a list of 1, with all of the data in 1 cell. Is there a way to separate them, so that each row will have the correspondent value from the original column?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as.list`

```
data <- as.list(sample_table$column)
```

Or use `split` :

```
data <- split(sample_table$column, seq(nrow(sample_table)))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ronak very nicely answered the question you *asked*, but perhaps you were hoping to extract the column and maintain the row-based `data.frame` structure?

In that case, you might try the `[` operator:

```
data <- sample_table["column"]
```